# MvvmCross is not installing

Tags: c#, nuget

Im trying to install the **mvvmcross** in a portable class library that supports **Wphone**, **Android**, and **iOS**!! Help Please. The error is:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport
>   3.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets  'portable-net45+sl40+wp80+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but
>   the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
>   that are compatible  with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Comment: "contact the package author", I don't think this is a question suitable for stack overflow

Comment: @Sayse this is a standard NuGet message, so the question is a valid NuGet question with enough details to diagnose. I just wish all questions were that well crafted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your project targets types not supported by the portable class library. For example, you are targetting Silverlight 4 (sl40), but the library you are trying to reference doesn't.

If you need to use the library and do not need to target all of the platforms you currently are, update what your PCL is targetting. If you do need to support all of the platforms you are targetting, you cannot use the library as it doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [nuspec](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/nuspec/MvvmCross.PortableSupport.3.0.1.nuspec) file at the 3.1 branch of MvvmCross, it seems that it supports Silverlight 5+. Your project targets SL4 so the package can't be installed.

You'll have to change the target versions for your project to include only those that MvvmCross supports.

You can check the supported versions by looking into the `packages` folder of your solution. This folder contains all installed packages and their contentes uncompressed to version-specific folders.